# Incorrect estimates of lm alternatives

Tags: r, lm

Dirk Eddelbuettel provides alternatives to estimating a linear regression with the `lm` command. See: http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/blog/2011/07/05/

However, he mentions:

> "Strictly-speaking, it is the only one we can compare to lm.fit()
>   which also uses a pivoting scheme. In the case of a degenerated model
>   matrix, all the other methods, including the four fastest approaches,
>   are susceptible to producing incorrect estimates."

Could someone **illustrate this point by providing an example** when the estimates are correct for lm, but not for the alternative approaches?

Comment: Dirk is on SOF, so he might come across your post...

Comment: This is really a request for statitical tutoring more than it is a coding question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install RcppArmadillo or RcppEigen and look at `help(fastLm)`:

```
   ## case where fastLm breaks down
   dd <- data.frame(f1 = gl(4, 6, labels = LETTERS[1:4]),
                    f2 = gl(3, 2, labels = letters[1:3]))[-(7:8), ]
   xtabs(~ f2 + f1, dd)     # one missing cell
   mm <- model.matrix(~ f1 * f2, dd)
   kappa(mm)                # large, indicating rank deficiency
   set.seed(1)
   dd$y <- mm %*% seq_len(ncol(mm)) + rnorm(nrow(mm), sd = 0.1)
   summary(lm(y ~ f1 * f2, dd))     # detects rank deficiency
   summary(fastLm(y ~ f1 * f2, dd)) # some huge coefficients
```

We owe this example to Doug Bates.